# Is it possible to insert column in the first postion with sas/sql

Tags: sql, sas

When I add a column to my my table with `alter table`, it is inserted as the last record. Is there a way to insert the column into the position I choose?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want that? You can always reorder the columns in the queries when `SELECT`ing from the table. So the order of the columns in the table shouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some dbms let you control the column position with an `alter table` statement, but most do not. [MySQL is one that does](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-options). Assume you start with

```
create table table_name (b char(1), d char(1));
```

You can alter that table to put column a first, and alter it again to put c after b.

```
alter table table_name add column a char(1) first;

alter table table_name add column c char(1) after b;
```

All dbms support "reordering" columns using `create view...` and `select...` though.

In the relational model of data, the order of columns is irrelevant. But I know what it's like to work in companies where that irrelevance is irrelevant.